# Maximum amount of data we can write to a CBPeripheral

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-bluetooth, cbcentralmanager, cbperipheral

What is the maximum amount of data we can write to a CBPeripheral through iOS BTLE. Is this 130 bytes?

Comment: I believe so, trying to find some documentation to verify

Comment: Yeah. Even I am trying to find out the documentation but no luck by far.

Comment: By frame? Because you can pass longs data (like for Over The Air Update for devices), in many frames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be 37 bytes of data per frame (you can find it at the beginning of the 3rd part of [this](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3478807/)).

**EDIT** : From Apple's WWDC classes, default MTU seems to be **23 bytes of data per frame**. If you have a developer account, you can find the video / pdf [here](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/videos/?id=703). I think these information is more relevant than the previous one.